# Learning MPI and Pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, parallel-processing, mpi, cpu-architecture

I have to learn about MPI and pthread for a parallel comp architecture course. The first half of this course will be based on parallel programming. I am not a CS major and don't have rigorous programming experience like CS people. So, I am a bit worried and would like to get some feedback from others who worked in these topics.

I have background in C and I am learning C++ & oop from last one month. So, will this background be a big issue if I want to learn about MPI, pthreads etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may issue problems with MPI/pthread key concepts that are language independent. Anyway a good knowledge of C(for pthread especially) will give you a hand. For pthread & MPI cpp/oop aren't so neccessary(they may be for some other library, eg. Intel TBB).

Comment: Can you refer me to a good learning resource for MPI and Pthread for beginner. I have started reading about MPI and using this: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node94.html#SECTION03500000000000000000 ..would appreciate to get some help :)

Comment: I found the book "Foundations of Multithreaded, Parallel, and Distributed Programming" by Andrews (http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~greg/mpdbook/) to be a good overview.  It has a little bit of everything, but you'll probably want other resources to fill in the details.  "Using MPI" by Gropp is good for MPI-specific stuff.  For Pthreads try this tutorial: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/.